# Best way to get Twilio SMS failures hourly or daily

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I couldn't find the best solution for this.
Since our failed delivery rate would be very low, probably less than 1%, maybe at the end of the day I could query all undelivered messages.
The ones with instant failures is no problems, these are just the ones the API doesn't spit back right away.

I could run through the status of each one with an API individually, but probably it's better if there's an API query to just get all the failures back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than gather up failures periodically I would set up a [`StatusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message) when you send the message and then collect the results using the webhook.

There's [a tutorial on doing this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery) which I recommend you take a look at.

Comment: Yes, but that could be a lot of call backs and a lot of traffic, say if I send 100k - 1 million messages. That's why I'm shying away from doing that. Or maybe it's better I that's I do it that way in the long run and just scale for a large amount of traffic.

Comment: If you're sending that many messages then I would recommend preparing the scale to receive the callbacks. Alternatively you could use a serverless service, something like [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions), to receive the callbacks and alert you of any failures.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can daily request to [Read multiple Message resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources) endpoint with `date_sent` param for messaging records and filter by delivery status on your server.

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC12345/Messages.csv?DateSent={YESTERDAY}&PageSize=1000
```

Many uses Twilio via some CRM which means callback resource could be in use for the service provider already. A query parameter for `delivery-status` must make it even easier.